# Returning difference between two nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have two objects and I would like to write a method (or better find a library) that returns object, that is a difference between those two, so having:

```
const sourceObject = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  address: {
    city: 'Zurich',
    registered_date: '2018-08-10',
    residents: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Amanda', phones: ['500600500', '500400300'] },
      { id: 2, name: 'Travis', phones: [] },
    ],
  },
  partner: {
    name: 'Clara Doe',
  },
  interests: ['valleys', 'oceans', 'hawaii'],
  phone_model: 'iPhone X',
};

const compareToObject = {
  name: 'John Doe-Manny',
  address: {
    city: 'Zurich',
    registered_date: '2019-08-10',
    residents: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Amanda', phones: ['500400300', '100200300'] },
    ],
  },
  partner: undefined,
  interests: ['valleys'],
  phone_model: undefined,
};
```

I would get as a result:

```
const expectedResult = {
  name: 'John Doe-Manny',
  address: {
    registered_date: '2019-08-10',
    residents: [
      { id: 1, phones: ['500400300', '100200300'] },
      { id: 2, deleted: true }, // See how deleted objects are handled
    ],
  },
  partner: undefined,
  phone_model: undefined,
};
```

I'm trying to figure out a way how to do this, or find a library but I have never failed so hard. I hate recursion.

Comment: is the structure is fixed  or it will vary?

Comment: Why would the `residents` attribute elements have `id` attributes, yet the `name` attribute disappears in the first element? There seems to be more to the rules than simple structural differences.

Comment: We are having deeply nested forms on the frontend, with moving parts and I'm trying to find a solution, so I only send what has been changed in the `PATCH` request. It seems so complicated that I'm about to do those comparisons manually.

Comment: @TedHopp The `name` disappears as it has not changed in the `comparedTo` object.

Comment: The `id` attributes also didn't change,  but it is preserved. This seems inconsistent.

Comment: `phones` array changed, so the `id` is sent so the backend knows in which `resident` the phones values should be changed.

Comment: Like I say, there seem to be rules at work that you haven't clearly expressed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem intriguing, so I wanted to take a crack at it. Unfortunately I can't afford to spend anymore time on it right now, so maybe someone else can take this the rest of the way. :-)

```js
const sourceObject = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  address: {
    city: 'Zurich',
    registered_date: '2018-08-10',
    residents: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Amanda', phones: ['500600500', '500400300'] },
      { id: 2, name: 'Travis', phones: [] },
    ],
  },
  partner: {
    name: 'Clara Doe',
  },
  interests: ['valleys', 'oceans', 'hawaii'],
  phone_model: 'iPhone X',
};

const compareToObject = {
  name: 'John Doe-Manny',
  address: {
    city: 'Zurich',
    registered_date: '2019-08-10',
    residents: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Amanda', phones: ['500400300', '100200300'] },
    ],
  },
  partner: undefined,
  interests: ['valleys'],
  phone_model: undefined,
};


var symb = 2039432423532453;//use symbol if supported

function diff(source, comp){
    if(! ['object', 'array'].includes(typeof(comp))){
        if(source !== comp){
            return comp;
        }
        return symb;
    }
    var out = {};
    for(var k in comp){
        var res = diff(source[k], comp[k]);
        if(res !== symb){
            out[k] = res;
        }
    }
    if(Object.keys(out).length != 0)
      return out;
    return symb;
}

console.log(diff(sourceObject, compareToObject));
```